# Why is this double render error appearing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app all of a sudden i keep getting a double render error (`Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at mos ....etc...`) and i could not for the life of me figure out where the double render is. It comes when the user types in a query that is not the proper format. Here is the code that checks the format and displays errors:

```
 def if_user_formulated_request_properly
    unless request.post?
      flash[:error] = "This page can only be accessed through the search page. (POST request only)"
      redirect_to(:action => "index") and return
    end
    if params[:query].blank?
      flash[:error] = "Search criteria can not be blank"
      redirect_to(:action => "index") and return
    end
    if !(params[:query] =~ /-/)
      flash[:error] = %( Format of search criteria is wrong.<br /> Should be [IXLSpecClass value][year]-[Message ID] for example GP07-8)
      redirect_to(:action => "index") and return
    end

    if !(QueryParser.expression.match(params[:query]))
      flash[:error] = %( Format of search criteria is wrong.<br /> Should be [IXLSpecClass value][year]-[Message ID] for example GP07-8)
      redirect_to(:action => "index") and return
    end
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Controller action code as requested:

```
def show
  if_user_formulated_request_properly do
    @input_messages = InputMessage.search_by(params[:query].strip) unless params[:query].blank?
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html #default rendering
  end
end
```

Comment: you always redirect to the same action, why do you duplicate these lines?

Comment: @apneadivin Because each line displays a different error message

Comment: yep but it doesn't prevent you from putting the `redirect_to` at the very end of your action.

Comment: @apneadiving No, because it only redirects if theres an error. If theres no error, nothing happens

Comment: what about `redirect_to (:action => "index") and return if flash[:error]`

Comment: @apenadiving Because this action isnt the main action of the controller, its an action called by a separate action.. based off what you suggest, what would happen if theres no errors? I do not want to redirect to the start of an action..

Comment: the `if` is here to redirect only when there is an error

Comment: @apneadiving Either way, i dont think this is the problem because it was working at one point.. i messed around with something but i cant figure out what cause the problem.

Comment: you need to paste in the controller action code

Comment: @klochner Updated my question with it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll suggest a refactoring for the action code and leave it to you to refactor the rest . . .

```
def show
  unless user_formulated_request_properly?
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
    return
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
  end
end
```

In case it's not obvious, you shouldn't have any redirect calls in `user_formulated_request_properly?`, and you shouldn't be calling yield either.  (imho, `yield` is the most overused ruby language feature)

Answer (score 2):

I'm making some assumptions about your code.

Assuming that if_user_formulated_request_properly is not the action of your controller, your controller action is calling this method.  When you do a return, you exit if_user_formulated_request_properly, but control goes back to the code in your action method.

I think you are expecting it to return from the action method, but that's not what happens.  Instead, it goes to the next line in the action.

Comment: You assumed correct! But it only goes to the next line if there was no error. If there was, it should stop there and just redirect. Instead, it displays the double render error